# Issue with function in for loop breaking the loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, google-apps-script

This code is intended to scan a sheet for currency values and build key/value pairs for a JSON based on the column and row headers.  So essentially, it finds a currency then backtracks row and column numbers until it hits a non-currency, non-blank value and uses that with the currency to form the pairs.  I have three functions I will list, the first is just to enable the second by determining if a value is currency, the second builds the object, the third iterates the sheets and builds the object for each sheet the meets my criteria.

Each sheet has a name that follows this pattern, "name_name_type_location", and my criteria is anything with the type "AF".

The issue I am having is that when I run tariffObject(sheets[i]) in publishedSheets() it seems to break the for loop, so I only ever receive the first sheet object, even though there are at least four that meet my criteria.  I have tested by removing the tariffObject(sheets[i]) call and it works fine.  Something about this is breaking my loop.

How do I fix this?

```
function isCurr(x){
  var regex  = /^[$]\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})$/;
  if (regex.test(x)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}

function tariffObject(sheet){
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var obj = {};
  var arr = [];
  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    for (j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
      if (isCurr(data[i][j])){
        //rows
        var y = i;
        while (isCurr(data[y][j]) || data[y][j].length <= 0){          
          y = y-1;
        }
        //columns
        var x = j;
        while (isCurr(data[i][x]) || data[i][x].length <= 0){
          x = x-1;
        }
        arr.push([data[i][x],data[y][j],data[i][j]]);
      }
    }
  }
  for (k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
    if (!obj[arr[k][0]]){
      obj[arr[k][0]] = {};
    }
    if (!obj[arr[k][0]][arr[k][1]]){
      obj[arr[k][0]][arr[k][1]] = {};
    }
    obj[arr[k][0]][arr[k][1]] = arr[k][2];
  }
  return obj;
}

function publishedSheets(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(my spreadsheet id),
      sheets = ss.getSheets(),
      loc = {};
  for (i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    var name = sheets[i].getName(),
        spl = name.split("_");
    if (spl[2] == "AF"){
      loc[spl[3]] = {};
      var myObj = tariffObject(sheets[i]);
      loc[spl[3]] = myObj;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(loc);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Two `while` loops inside of a `for` loop inside of a `for` loop is screaming "anti-pattern". Whatever it is you are trying to do, there is most certainly another way.

Comment: The while loops are on the same level, not within each other, and they determine the row and column headers respectively.  I believe a for loop in a for loop is pretty common to iterate a spreadsheet.  While I agree that there is undoubtedly a better way, this part works.

Comment: I didn't say the `while` loops were nested within each other. But one `for` loop should do rows and another should do `columns`, so nested `while` loops seem incorrect. If they are for headers, they should be outside of the loops that get the content.

Comment: Hmm, well, the headers are not in fixed locations.  The number of columns and rows may vary, and the position of the currency table within the spreadsheet may vary as well.  The easiest solution I had was to find the currency value and get the header in relation to that.  Since it is unknown, I cannot think of a better way to do that.  If you have an idea, I will happily test it.

Comment: Can you provide an image of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Added, I had to reduce it down to the base currency table as there is sensitive information in other places, but this is the basic layout.  So my JSON would read as:  Area A={MINIMUM CHARGE=$16.00,100=$9.00,1000=$8.40,2000=$8.00,3000=$7.00,5000=$6.00,CAP=$350.00},Area B={...etc

Comment: Hi there @NMALM! I understand that the issue is the `var myObj = tariffObject(sheets[i]);` statement inside the `publishedSheets()` function, because it causes a faulty execution of the function. To prevent issues in `tariffObject()`, could you please isolate that function and confirm if it runs properly?

Comment: tariffObject() runs as anticipated when ran for one sheet.  In a loop though, it breaks the loop upon the first resolving.  So I end up with 1 sheet having been converted to a JSON, but there should be 4 matches.  When I remove tariffObject() from the loop, I can verify that there is in fact 4 key/value pairs created (with empty values, ofc).  So something in tariffObject() function is breaking my loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function creatingJson() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let jObj = { pA: [] };
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (j == 0) {
        jObj[c] = {};
        jObj.pA.push(c);
      } else {
        jObj[vs[i][0]][hA[j]] = c;
      }
    });
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(jObj));
  hA.shift();
  let s = '';
  jObj.pA.forEach((p, i) => {
    s += p + "={";
    hA.forEach((h, j) => {
      if (j > 0) s += ',';
      s += h + "=" + jObj[p][h];
    });
    s+='}\n';
  });
  Logger.log(s);

}
```

Sheet1:

|  | H1 | H2 | H3 | H4 | H5 | H6 | H7 | H8 | H9 | H10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 1 | 11 | 21 | 31 | 41 | 51 | 61 | 71 | 81 | 91 |
| R2 | 2 | 12 | 22 | 32 | 42 | 52 | 62 | 72 | 82 | 92 |
| R3 | 3 | 13 | 23 | 33 | 43 | 53 | 63 | 73 | 83 | 93 |
| R4 | 4 | 14 | 24 | 34 | 44 | 54 | 64 | 74 | 84 | 94 |
| R5 | 5 | 15 | 25 | 35 | 45 | 55 | 65 | 75 | 85 | 95 |
| R6 | 6 | 16 | 26 | 36 | 46 | 56 | 66 | 76 | 86 | 96 |
| R7 | 7 | 17 | 27 | 37 | 47 | 57 | 67 | 77 | 87 | 97 |
| R8 | 8 | 18 | 28 | 38 | 48 | 58 | 68 | 78 | 88 | 98 |
| R9 | 9 | 19 | 29 | 39 | 49 | 59 | 69 | 79 | 89 | 99 |
| R10 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 60 | 70 | 80 | 90 | 100 |

Output:

```
R1={H1=1,H2=11,H3=21,H4=31,H5=41,H6=51,H7=61,H8=71,H9=81,H10=91}
R2={H1=2,H2=12,H3=22,H4=32,H5=42,H6=52,H7=62,H8=72,H9=82,H10=92}
R3={H1=3,H2=13,H3=23,H4=33,H5=43,H6=53,H7=63,H8=73,H9=83,H10=93}
R4={H1=4,H2=14,H3=24,H4=34,H5=44,H6=54,H7=64,H8=74,H9=84,H10=94}
R5={H1=5,H2=15,H3=25,H4=35,H5=45,H6=55,H7=65,H8=75,H9=85,H10=95}
R6={H1=6,H2=16,H3=26,H4=36,H5=46,H6=56,H7=66,H8=76,H9=86,H10=96}
R7={H1=7,H2=17,H3=27,H4=37,H5=47,H6=57,H7=67,H8=77,H9=87,H10=97}
R8={H1=8,H2=18,H3=28,H4=38,H5=48,H6=58,H7=68,H8=78,H9=88,H10=98}
R9={H1=9,H2=19,H3=29,H4=39,H5=49,H6=59,H7=69,H8=79,H9=89,H10=99}
R10={H1=10,H2=20,H3=30,H4=40,H5=50,H6=60,H7=70,H8=80,H9=90,H10=100}
```

The output is generated from this object:

```
{"pA":["R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8","R9","R10"],"R1":{"H1":1,"H2":11,"H3":21,"H4":31,"H5":41,"H6":51,"H7":61,"H8":71,"H9":81,"H10":91},"R2":{"H1":2,"H2":12,"H3":22,"H4":32,"H5":42,"H6":52,"H7":62,"H8":72,"H9":82,"H10":92},"R3":{"H1":3,"H2":13,"H3":23,"H4":33,"H5":43,"H6":53,"H7":63,"H8":73,"H9":83,"H10":93},"R4":{"H1":4,"H2":14,"H3":24,"H4":34,"H5":44,"H6":54,"H7":64,"H8":74,"H9":84,"H10":94},"R5":{"H1":5,"H2":15,"H3":25,"H4":35,"H5":45,"H6":55,"H7":65,"H8":75,"H9":85,"H10":95},"R6":{"H1":6,"H2":16,"H3":26,"H4":36,"H5":46,"H6":56,"H7":66,"H8":76,"H9":86,"H10":96},"R7":{"H1":7,"H2":17,"H3":27,"H4":37,"H5":47,"H6":57,"H7":67,"H8":77,"H9":87,"H10":97},"R8":{"H1":8,"H2":18,"H3":28,"H4":38,"H5":48,"H6":58,"H7":68,"H8":78,"H9":88,"H10":98},"R9":{"H1":9,"H2":19,"H3":29,"H4":39,"H5":49,"H6":59,"H7":69,"H8":79,"H9":89,"H10":99},"R10":{"H1":10,"H2":20,"H3":30,"H4":40,"H5":50,"H6":60,"H7":70,"H8":80,"H9":90,"H10":100}}
```

Comment: This almost works perfect.  The only issue becomes the bottom rows with time/area, as the dynamic changes a bit.  The JSON needs to then be: Monday-Friday 0800-1700={Area A=$40.00,Area B=$55.00,Area C=$65.00,Area D=$90.00} and what I'm getting is:
TIME={MINIMUM CHARGE=,100=,1000=,2000=Area A,3000=Area B,5000=Area C,CAP=Area D}
Monday-Friday 0800-1700={MINIMUM CHARGE=,100=,1000=,2000=40,3000=55,5000=65,CAP=90}

Comment: But that is a great piece of code to work from.  Thank you!

Comment: I would not try to do different ranges with the same script.  When I work with complicated spreadsheets I always require that I have control over certain cells that I can use to determine where ranges can be found programmatically.  If clients don't give me what I need I walk and let them figure it out for themselves.  Another option is using meta data in a way that I heard Bruce McPherson describe once but it was totally over my head and I have no intention of learning it.  I always construct my own work based upon making the code as easy as possible.

Comment: The other issue is that this is only a small part of the full sheet, which I can't share.  So it requires iterating through the sheet to programmatically tell where to start creating the JSON, which I thought would be easiest by looking for currency, since it is unique to what I need